# Paging through an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable object (`IEnumerable<Class>`) and I would like to retrieve a specified line from the object. So if I'm on page two I would like to select row two from the IEnumerable object and then pass it on to another class etc.

I'm a bit stuck at the moment, any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at the functions `.Take()` and `.Skip()`. I normally do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<object> GetPage(IEnumerable<object> input, int page, int pagesize)
{
     return input.Skip(page*pagesize).Take(pagesize);
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is 0-based. To call the first page you need to pass 0.

Comment: Why yes, because doing 1-based indexing is just needlessly complex. Especially when dealing with C# that uses 0-based indexing.

Comment: Is it really worth mentioning that it's 0-based? I imagine that that's a baseline assumption. It'd be worth mentioning if it was 1-based for some odd reason

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly, something like this paging mechanism should work:

```
int pageSize = 10;
int pageCount = 2;

iEnumerable.Skip(pageSize*pageCount).Take(pageSize);
```

This example shows 10 rows per page and a page number of 2. So, it will skip to page 2 and take the first row on that page.

Comment: Actually that would `Take` the first 2 results after the skip, but the `Skip` portion is the right idea.

Comment: Your arithmetic is slightly off. The second row on the second page has index 11, not 20 (assuming 10 rows per page, and that rows and pages start at index 1).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that pages and rows start at 1, and there is a fixed number of rows per page (say 10), you need to transform the page number and the row to an index as follows:

```
Page    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3 ...
Row     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3 ...
                                         ↓
Index   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 ...
```

Code:

```
int page = 2;
int row = 2;

int rowsPerPage = 10;

IEnumerable<MyClass> source = ...

MyClass result = source.ElementAt((page - 1) * rowsPerPage + (row - 1));
```

So to get row 2 on page 2, you need to skip the first page (10 elements) and then take the second element (index 1 in that page).

Comment: -1 Extremely overcomplicated and inefficient for what the original requirements are.

Comment: @Timothy Baldridge: It's inefficient if you do this to get every element on a page. But the OP states he wants to get only a single element on a specific page. So I wouldn't say that a simple ElementAt is overcomplicated or inefficient here.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a dynamic solution in vb.net, i hope helpful:

```
 <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function Paginate(Of T As {Class})(source As T, skip As Integer, take As Integer) As T
    If source IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf source Is IEnumerable Then

        Dim chunk = (From c In DirectCast(source, IEnumerable)).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList
        If chunk.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing

        Return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(chunk, GetType(T), GetType(T))
    End If
    Return source
End Function
```